# Getting everything, except when starts with \t (indent)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know if there is a way to match everything in text, except when starts with \t (indent char). I'm currently trying to achieve that with the literal `/[^\t]+\t/gm`, but it doesn't work properly as you can see [here](https://regexr.com/45l1k):

RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported.

The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.

```
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
    something
    something2
```

Everything up the first something is being matched. The desired result is to stop on the "English" word.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have *two* matches there - one match, containing *most* of the text, and stopping at the tab character just before `something`. You then have a *second* match, containing the `something` and the following tab character on the next line.

Since it sounds like you don't actually want to match the tab character, don't match `\t` - you might use `\S` to make sure that the last matched character is a non-whitespace character. Also, to make sure matches start at the beginning of a line, use `^` to anchor (so that text after a `\t` doesn't get matched):

```
^[^\t]+\S
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand from your example you want to match all the strings which is not starting with a `\t` character.

You can use this

```
^[^\t\n][\w\W]*?$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `[^\t\n]` - Assert to not match string start with tab or empty.
- `[\w\W]*?`- Match anything zero or more time(lazy mode).
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZV236/7)

Sample code

```js
const regex = /^[^\t\n][\w\W]*?$/gm;
const str = `Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
 something
 something2
Hey how are you
 is this what you wanted to achieve
string with  tab inside

  hello
hello       end

v
v


`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```